# Excel VBA keeping input parameters gathered in an input area

Tags: vba, excel, input

Currently, I am working on a VBA project with quite a lot of required subroutines. What I want to do is to create an 'Input Function' that contains all of my basic input parameters for the code.

At the moment I need to declare my variables in each subroutine which means that if one of them changes, I need to go through the whole code to change them. Having one input domain makes it possible to just make one change instead of going through an entire module.

In MATLAB I would create a separate script with i.e. the struct "Input" that contains all the input data. Running the script in my main script would then generate all the parameters ready to be used.

Is something similar possible in VBA? I have look at class functions and declaring variables outside subroutines but does not look like the best solution.

Comment: Why are you dismissing an OO solution?  I can't think of a better way to hold state than a class.

Comment: You can use a custom `Type` (similar to a struct) in VBA.

Comment: While global variables are often considered poor design, there are valid uses of them. Perhaps this is one of them. If you are talking about global parameters (which you seem to) why not declare them as global (public) variables?

Answer (score 0):

While Global Variables are generally frowned upon, this seems like the perfect place for Global variables...

Typically GVs are avoided due to their impact on performance, the possibility of them getting confused with local variables with similar names, and the perceived sloppiness of using them instead of taking the time to set up proper variables across your procedures and subs... but if those potential negatives are not important factors for what your macro would be doing, and/or compensated for/mitigated in your code, then there's no reason not to use them..

My 2 cents- if the benefit from using GVs exceeds the downsides to them for your particular situation then use them!

Hope this helps,
TheSilkCode